# Mvc add id and css class in MVC Html.BeginForm()

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I am new to MVC.

How I can add id and css class in MVC Html.BeginForm().

This is html form.

```
<form id="frmId" class="frmStyle">
    ...
</form>
```

I tried this but got error.

```
@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", new {id="frmId", class = "frmStyle"})
```

Answer (score 36, accepted):

We add as part of htmlAttributes.

```
@Html.BeginForm("actionName", "controllerName", FormMethod.Post,
 new {id="frmId", @class = "frmStyle"})
```

Comment: why does `id` need to add a `@` before it?

Comment: The `@` character before the property names escapes them, so as not to clash with C# keywords. `class` is a keyword. You would get a compiler error if you didn't escape them. Not entirely sure why `id` is escaped in this answer though; AFAIK it's not a keyword.

Comment: @ is only needed for @class